# Scala Function.tupled vs f.tupled

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tuples, flatmap

I have the following Scala code:

```
def f(x: Int, y: Int): Option[String] = x*y match {
    case 0 => None
    case n => Some(n.toString)
}

val data = List((0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 3), (4, -1))

data flatMap {case (x, y) => f(x, y)}
```

But, the last line is too verbose so I tried all of these and none of them compiles.

`data flatMap f`

`data flatMap f.tupled`

`data flatMap Function.tupled(f)`

`data flatMap {f _}`

`data flatMap (f _).tupled`

`data flatMap f(_)`

What am I doing wrong? The only thing that works is this:

`(data map Function.tupled(f)).flatten`

I thought a `map` followed by `flatten` can always be replaced by `flatMap`, but although the above line compiles, this does not:

`data flatMap Function.tupled(f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `flatMap` when returning `Options` because there is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable` by the implicit `option2Iterable`.  The method `flatMap` on your `List[(Int, Int)]` expects a function from `(Int, Int)` to `GenTraversableOnce[Int]`. The compiler is having trouble identifying that implicit conversion as a viable option here.  You can help the compiler along by explicitly specifying your generic parameters:

```
import Function._
data.flatMap[String, Iterable[String]](tupled(f))
//Or
data flatMap tupled[Int, Int, Iterable[String]](f)
```

Other formulations of the same idea might also allow the compiler to pick the correct types and implicits, even without the explicit generics:

```
data flatMap (tupled(f _)(_))
data.flatMap (f.tupled(f _)(_))
```

Finally, you might also want to play with `collect` together with `unlift` here, which can be a nice way to express this logic as well:

```
data collect unlift((f _).tupled)
data collect unlift(tupled(f))
```

`Function.unlift` takes a method that returns an `Option` and turns it into `PartialFunction` that doesn't match where the original function would return `None`.  `collect` takes a partial function and collects the values of a the partial function if it is defined at each element.

Comment: `data collect unlift(tupled(f))` makes more sense here IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To further the very helpful answer above, if you use `collect`, you can then go a step further and rewrite your function f as a Partial Function:

```
val f: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), String] = {
  case (x, y) if x*y != 0 => (x*y).toString
}
```

You can then process your data thus:

```
data collect f
```

In general, any function that returns an Option can be re-written as a partial function.  In some cases this comes out neater as you have fewer `case` expressions and don't have to wrap the return values in `Some()`.